# New Asp.Net Project Template Dialog is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I have (just reinstalled) Visual Studio 2013 Professional (on Win 8.1) to try and fix this: If I try to create a new Web Project, for either .Net 4.5 or 4.5.1, then I see the screen below.

If I try to open an existing MVC 5 website (one I've just created through that wizard on another machine) - then it works just fine.

Equally, if I set the target framework to 4 then I get the previous MVC 4 template appear, and *that* works.

If I look in the `Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\Web\CSharp\1033\` folder then I see `WebApplication45` which appears to contain the content that this project template uses - so why is it broken!?

The machine did *use* to have VS2012 on it, and I notice that in the list of installed products for 2013 it has 'ASP.Net Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2' - which I believe is a VS 2012 thing.  So I'm wondering if that's interfering with it.  But there's nothing on my Add/Remove programmes for this, so I don't know how to uninstall it!

Any help greatly appreciated before I throw my screen through the window :)

[image: Empty 'new ASP.Net project' dialog]

Comment: Check is there any updates available for your VS2013, Menu >> Tools >>  Etentions and Updates

Comment: hi - no there are no updates available related to asp.net.  Advertising SDK and Mobile SDK only

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following:

1. Close VS, open Explorer and go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
   Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
2. Delete the following assemblies if they exist:

   - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Contracts.dll
   - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Explorer.dll
   - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Internal.Contracts.dll
3. Restart VS

Comment: Removing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Contracts.dll and
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Explorer.dll fixed this for me, reinstating the ASP.NET Project Templates. I didn't have the Internal.Contracts assembly.

Answer (score 0):

In Tools > Extensions and Updates:

1. Update to lates VS2013 update (it is Update 3 now)
2. Install if not installed Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools
3. Install if not installed ASP.NET Web Forms MVC 4
4. Install if not installed MS VS ASP.NET MVC 5 Scaffolding

Comment: thanks for your answer - all are installed unfortunately.  I've removed old versions of azure sdk (apparently the web tools are packaged in that now) that were laying around too; no joy.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing all programs connected with .Net development and SQL (just being really cutthroat) - not just Visual Studio; going down my installed programs list from top to bottom:

- Visual Studio 2013, obviously
- All .Net Framework SDKs and Language Targeting Packs
- All Azure tools SDKs (some start with 'Azure', one starts 'Windows Azure')
- All SQL Server stuff - possibly too much, but I didn't need them outside of VS
- IIS Express

I then rebooted and deleted all remaining Microsoft Visual Studio folders (I had v10, 11 and 12) from `Program Files (x86)` and all remaining SQL Server folders.  SQL is also in the x64 program files, and that's used legitimately by the OS, so might want to skip that one.

I then rebooted again and reinstalled 2013 with Update 3 - and now the new project dialog works as expected.

It's most likely the removal of just one of those things that fixed it (my money is on clearing down the VS folders).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by deleting these files from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies:

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Contracts.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Explorer.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Internal.Contracts.dll

(based on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/08/04/vs-tfs-2013-3-update-3-released.aspx#10550199).